# encrypt credentials making rest api get method call

Tags: python

I am using the below code to read response from an api. I am stuck with how to encrypt credentials. I get invalid syntax error.

```
import requests
from base64 import b64encode

user = "usr"
password = "pwd"

response = requests.get('https://myapi/v1/api',
                        auth=(user, password) # invalid syntax
data = response.json()
```

Comment: you are missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis in this line at the end:

`response = requests.get('https://myapi/v1/api', auth=(user, password))`

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the below code to read response from an api. I am stuck with how to encrypt credentials.

`https` already encrypts the request, so you don't need to do anything special here.

> I get invalid syntax error.

You get this error because you are missing a closing parenthese.